# Inherited method not working

Tags: java, inheritance, methods

I have a method that is supposed to replenish stock parts for a manufacturer. I have tried using super.Method() but its not working. There's also a class called Part if it's needed.

Main Class

```
package main;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestAssembledPart {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    List<AssembledPart> aparts = new ArrayList<AssembledPart>();
    aparts.add(new AssembledPart("a200", "Crank & Pedal", 10, 3.5, "Crank", "Pedal"));

     System.out.println("part before stock level change - start");
     System.out.println(AssembledPart.toAssembledString(aparts));

     for (AssembledPart apart: aparts){
         if(apart!=null){
             System.out.println("Please enter replenish quantity");
             aparts.replenish(sc.nextInt());
         }
     }
     System.out.println("part before stock level change - end");
     System.out.println(AssembledPart.toAssembledString(aparts));
}

}
```

AssembledPart Class

```
package main;
import java.util.*;

public class AssembledPart extends Part {

private String basica;
private String basicb;
private int assembledstocklevel;

public AssembledPart(String id, String name, int stocklevel, double unitprice, 
                    String basica, String basicb) {

    super(id, name, stocklevel, unitprice);

    this.basica = basica;
    this.basicb = basicb;
}

public void replenish(int qty){
    super.replenish(qty);
    //super.stocklevel = super.stocklevel + qty;
}

public String toAssembledString() {
    return super.toString() + " | " + basica + " | " + basicb;
}   
public static String toAssembledString(Collection<AssembledPart> aparts){
    String s = "";
    for (AssembledPart apart: aparts){
        s += apart.toAssembledString() + "\n";
    }
    return s;
}
}
```

PartClass

```
package main;
import java.util.*;

public class Part {

private String id;
private String name;
protected int stocklevel;
private double unitprice;

private int qty = 6000;

public Part(String id, String name, int stocklevel, double unitprice){
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.stocklevel = stocklevel;
    this.unitprice = unitprice;
}


String partsAvailable()
{
    //String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    return (id + "\t" + name + "\t    " + stocklevel + "\t\t   " + unitprice);
}


public String getID() {
    return id;
}

public void setID(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getStockLevel(){
    return stocklevel - qty;
}

public void setStockLevel(int stocklevel){
    this.stocklevel = stocklevel;
}

public double getUnitPrice(){
    return unitprice;
}

public void setUnitPrice(double unitprice){
    this.unitprice = unitprice;
}

public void replenish(int qty){
    this.stocklevel = stocklevel + qty;
}

public double supply(int qty){
    return unitprice * qty;
}

public String toString() {
    return id + " | " + name + " | " + stocklevel + " | " + unitprice;
}


public static String toString(Collection<Part> parts){
    String s = "";
    for (Part part: parts){
        s += part + "\n";
    }
    return s;
}


}
```

Comment: *I have tried using super.Method() but its not working.* What is not working? Be specific.

Comment: Error ? Exception ? Broke ? Crash ? What not working ?

Comment: in my main class, aparts.replenish(sc.nextInt()). the method is underlined in red.

Comment: where is the Part class?

Comment: Also show the super class `Part`

Comment: the method replenish(int) is undefined for the type List<AssembledPart>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this line :

```
         aparts.replenish(sc.nextInt());
```

With the following

```
         apart.replenish(sc.nextInt());
```

You were actually calling a method on the collection that contains your objects instead of the objects themself.